# Already employed and have 2 job offers. Both of them accepted

Tags: software-industry, job-offer, california, software-development

I am currently working. The reason I started looking for a job was my spouse's job was relocated and my company does not promote telecommuting.

so I started interviewing. And hence I currently have 2 job offers: company A and company B. After the initial interview I declined to proceed any further with company A, since the work was not very interesting. But a few days later the recruiters came back to me saying that the manager really wanted me at least reconsider, and that he was really impressed with me and wanted me to at least come in talk to the rest of the team  etc.

I went in there a few days later after lot of coaxing from recruiters, and since I did not have any other offers I accepted the CONSULTING offer from Company A 10 days ago. I wanted more time to consider the offer from company A but the recruiters gave me a just a few hours to think. Not having any other offers I accepted it.

Today I got an FULL TIME offer from Company B, a well established stable company, which is good and under immense pressure from the recruiter accepted that as well. I have already given notice at my current company and the start date at company A has been fixed to 2 weeks from now. I prefer to work at company B since it is a full time job offer. But what do I now do with company A ?

I could delay the start date at company B, work with company A for a couple of weeks and then say that this kind of work is not what I really want to do.

If I tell them now, then I have burned the bridge with the company and the recruiting company as well.

What should I do ?

Note: Signed the acceptance from Company A. Completed background checks. Submitted W4 etc. Nothing signed with Company B yet. Will be starting with the background checks and drug test etc.

Comment: Any company and/or recruiter that demands an answer within just a few hours deserves what they get.

Comment: What about Company A ? Should I start there and then say this commute is not working or the work is not what I would like to do ?

Comment: No just contact them and say that it just is not going to work out at this time.  Apologise and give them no specific reason, thank them for consideration and move on.

Comment: Because you have not completed all the pre-hiring steps for company B you don't have a solid offer. You could still lose the job.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not intending to stay with company A, then stringing them along "for a couple of weeks" and *then* telling them is *not* going to help matters. You will burn bridges a lot worse doing that than you will if you tell them *now* that you don't want to take the job.

Have you signed a contract with company A yet? Signed a written offer? How about company B?

If you have signed acceptance of both jobs, then you have done a very foolish thing and put yourself in a very bad situation. In this case, there is nothing to be done other than break your word with one of the two companies, in which case you might as well break it with company A, since you'd prefer not to work with them.

If these acceptances are only verbal, that was still very foolish but is not as damaging a situation. Company A will still be displeased if you renege on your agreement, but they will just have to accept it.

I can't see any way out of this situation without you burning bridges with one company and one recruiter. So all you can do is:

- Pick which one you want to burn your bridges with - it sounds like Company A
- Do it *as quickly as possible*. Every day you delay makes it more inconvenient for them when you break the news that they actually need to restart their search for a new employee.

Comment: Signed the acceptance from Company A. Completed background checks. Submitted W4 etc. Nothing signed with Company B yet. Will be starting with the background checks and drug test etc.

Comment: @NatashaCurry the honourable thing to do would be to take the job at company A. But if you're confident that the Company B job would be so much better for your career, then take the hit, tell Company A you've changed your mind, and accept that you'll make them and the recruiter very angry.